# 400 Bad Request when trying to send data to ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, jquery-ajax

I am trying to upload some files by sending it to an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, but when I call the API, it throwing a 400 error. Please help me solve the issue.

File upload model:

```
public class FileUploadModel
{
    public IFormFile[] Files { get; set; }
}
```

Web API action method:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(FileUploadModel model)
{
    if (model.Files == null || model.Files.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No files selected");
    }

    foreach (var file in model.Files)
    {
        if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        {
            // Skip optional files that were not uploaded
            continue;
        }

        var uniqueFileName = $@"{Guid.NewGuid()}{file.FileName}";

        var filePath = Path.Combine("/Uploads", uniqueFileName);

        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        // code to write file path to Database

        return Ok("Files uploaded successfully");
    }
}
```

API call using jQuery Ajax from frontend:

```
// Initialize a FormData object
var formData = new FormData();

// Add the files to the FormData object
formData.append("file1", $("#payslip")[0].files[0], "payslip");
formData.append("file2", $("#experience")[0].files[0], "experience");
formData.append("file3", $("#pg")[0].files[0], "pg");
formData.append("file4", $("#degree")[0].files[0], "degree");
formData.append("file5", $("#plustwo")[0].files[0], "plustwo");
formData.append("file6", $("#sslc")[0].files[0], "sslc");

// Make the Ajax call
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:7049/api/SelectedCandidates/UploadFiles",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (result) {
                alert("documents uploaded successfully");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("error "+status);
                console.log(error);
        }
});
```

When I try to call the API, I get a HTTP 400 Bad Request error and none of the code inside the `UploadFiles` API method is working. I am new to .NET Core, please help me to figure out the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: FileModel is just an object, it's not a `FormData`, you would need to add `[FromForm]` attribute to it.